# Foreign key constraints are not allowed (Prisma)

Tags: mysql, prisma, planetscale

Currently facing an issue whilst attempting to push schema changes to planetscale db. Not sure what I may be doing wrong. I am fairly new to prisma, so I would appreciate some help :).

```
generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id    String @id @default(uuid())
  notes Note[]
}

model Note {
  id     String @id @default(uuid())
  userId String @unique
  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}
```

Tried migrating. If the relation of one to many is removed, the error goes away.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). 
Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the 
problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: At a guess, also dont know prisma, it need to know which table the `references:[id]`  exists in!

Comment: I tried your schema file locally and didn't get any error. Can you try running `npx prisma format` and see if you still get the error?

Comment: Nothing :(. It gives me the following error: ```Error: foreign key constraints are not allowed, see https://vitess.io/blog/2021-06-15-online-ddl-why-no-fk/```

Comment: Seems like adding ```relationMode = "prisma"``` fixes my issue. Thank you both for your help :).

Comment: I am glad to hear that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 19):

In your `schema.prisma` file

```js
datasource db {
  provider     = "mysql"
  url          = env("DATABASE_URL")
  
  // Add this
  relationMode = "prisma"
}
```

The reason can be found in the [prisma documentation for relationMode](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/relation-mode#how-to-set-the-relation-mode-in-your-prisma-schema). It states the following:

> For relational databases, the available options are:
>
> - `foreignKeys`: this handles relations in the database with foreign keys. This is the default option for all relational database connectors and is active if no `relationMode` is explicitly set in the `datasource` block.
> - `prisma`: this emulates relations in the Prisma client. You should also enable this option when you use the MySQL connector with a PlanetScale database.